# Why does useState is returning undefined in output?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I am providing `isFollowing=true` here
but in useState`followButtonState` is returning undefined as output.

```js
const [followButtonState, setFollowButtonState] = useState(isFollowing);
console.log(`profile info component: ${isFollowing}`); //output :true
console.log(followButtonState); //output :undefined
```

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: where is `setFollowButtonState()` method to initialize `followButtonState` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are passing `isFollowing` as a prop to your component then set the value of `followButtonState` in **useEffect** instead of directly assigning it:

```
const [followButtonState, setFollowButtonState] = useState('');

React.useEffect(() => {
  setFollowButtonState(isFollowing)
}, [isFollowing)
```

I hope this will solve your issue.

Comment: thank you man!! it worked perfectly fine